# Use php to extract data from JSON and implement in HTML drop down menu

Tags: php, html, leaflet, geojson

I have been set a task to create a PHP routine to return the ISO code and name for inclusion from a geojson in the  of countries drop-down for a website.

This is entirely new to this and really struggling with the documentation.

I've created a html drop-down in the navigation bar

```
      <nav id="navbar" class="navbar">
        <ul>
          <li class="dropdown"><a href="#"><span>Please Select a Country to Learn More!</span> <i class="bi bi-chevron-down"></i></a>

        <i class="bi bi-list mobile-nav-toggle"></i>
      </nav>
```

and this is a sample of the GeoJSON file I've been supplied with

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {
                "name": "Bahamas",
                "iso_a2": "BS",
                "iso_a3": "BHS",
                "iso_n3": "044"
            },
            "geometry": {
                "type": "MultiPolygon",
                "coordinates": [
                    [
                        [
                            [
                                -77.53466,
                                23.75975
                            ],
                            [
                                -77.78,
                                23.71
                            ],
                            [
                                -78.03405,
                                24.28615
                            ],
                            [
                                -78.40848,
                                24.57564
                            ],
                            [
                                -78.19087,
                                25.2103
                            ],
                            [
                                -77.89,
                                25.17
                            ],
                            [
                                -77.54,
                                24.34
                            ],
                            [
                                -77.53466,
                                23.75975
                            ]
                        ]
                    ],
```

What I'm wanting to do is ensure all country names in the geojson are available in my drop-down, and when selected they navigate to the correct area on a leaflet map.

I have the leaflet map set up currently.

I've attempted the PHP script, but have no idea if I'm on the right track or how to use it to achieve what I want

```
<?php 

$executionStartTime = microtime(true) / 1000;



$json = json_decode(file_get_contents("../geojson/countries_small.geo.json"), true);

    foreach ($json['features'] as $feature) {
            $temp = null;
            $temp['code'] = $feature["id"];
            $temp['name'] = $feature['properties']['name'];

            array_push($country, $temp);
        }

    $output['status']['code'] = "200";
    $output['status']['name'] = "ok";
    $output['status']['description'] = "mission saved";
    $output['status']['returnedIn'] = (microtime(true) - $executionStartTime) / 1000 . " ms";
    $output['data'] = $decode;

    header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');

    echo json_encode($output); 

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple variables that aren't initialised (readability is key ^_^)
If I've correctly understood what you're trying to do, then here's how I would do it (I've just tweaked your existing code)

```
<?php 

$executionStartTime = microtime(true) / 1000;

try {
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents("../geojson/countries_small.geo.json"), true);
$country = array();

foreach ($json['features'] as $feature) {
    $country[$feature["id"]] = $feature['properties']['name'];
}

//Rather use proper header codes, unless you really need to send this
/*
$output['status']['code'] = "200";
$output['status']['name'] = "ok";
*/
$output['status']['description'] = "mission saved";
$output['status']['returnedIn'] = (microtime(true) - $executionStartTime) / 1000 . " ms";
$output['data'] = $country;

http_response_code(200);
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');

echo json_encode($output);
} catch (Exception $Exception) {
    http_response_code(500);
    
    //display $Exception->getMessage(), or whatever you need to do here if there's an error
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you! How can I go about ensuring they are called and display in my HTML drop-down?

Comment: @user09873920134 That is a veeery open ended question O.o The answer to that literally all depends on how you're building your site. Are you hitting an API to retrieve your drop down options on page load (or some other event), or are you just planning on populating your drop down using PHP when the page is requested??? If it's the 1st, then that requires a whole bunch of javascript. The latter would be easier if it fits with what you want to achieve ;)